# Android get TabView from TabLayout after using setupWithViewPager

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

I am lazy so I use this instead of creating different TabView

```
    v = new myTabContent(c);//my custom viewpager
    t = new TabLayout(c);
    t.setupWithViewPager(v);
```

I wonder if there is any ways to get all the TabView from the TabLayout, because I want to set longclicklistener to each TabView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TabView` essentially is a `HorizontalScrollView` that hosts a `SlidingTabStrip` a `LinearLayout` for each tab.

Simple iteration over the `SlidingTabStrip` will give you the `TabView`s:

```
    LinearLayout tabStrip = (LinearLayout) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < tabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View tabView = tabStrip.getChildAt(i);
        if (tabView != null){
          //do something with the TabView
        }
    }
}
```

However this has to be performed after `TabLayout` has successfully been laid out.

Answer (score 0):

```
            TabLayout.Tab tab =  tabLayout.newTab();

            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(TagsManagerActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.item_tab, null);
            ((TextView)linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(tagsManagerTab.getTagNameRes());
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                ((ImageView)linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(tagsManagerTab.getIconRes(),TagsManagerActivity.this.getTheme()));
            else
                ((ImageView)linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(tagsManagerTab.getIconRes()));

            tab.setCustomView(linearLayout);
            tabLayout.addTab(tab);
```